# 301 redirect based on variable in the POST

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect

so i need to send certain search POSTs to a different url...

```
www.xyz.com/search-results.php?city%5B%5D=Boynton+Beach&proptype=rental&foreclosure=&price_from=0&price_to=0&footage_from=&footage_to=&bedrooms_from=&bedrooms_to=&bathrooms_from=&bathrooms_to=&pets=&year_from=&year_to=&pool=
```

in this case i need to parse out the `proptype=rental` and send the whole thing to

```
www.xyzRentals.com/search-results.php?city%5B%5D=Boynton+Beach&proptype=rental&foreclosure=&price_from=0&price_to=0&footage_from=&footage_to=&bedrooms_from=&bedrooms_to=&bathrooms_from=&bathrooms_to=&pets=&year_from=&year_to=&pool=
```

i know i need to add some regex to parse the url in the .htaccess file and do a 301...any quick ideas how to get this done?  I've tried

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^search-results.php?(.*)proptype=rental(.*)$   http://www.xyzRentals.com/search-results.php?$1proptype=rental$2
```

but not working and i'm not sure why...when i put the regex into a matcher it says it DOES match but still no redirect.

ANSWER

so I ended doing it in jquery...

```
var searchType = $('#proptype').val();

if (searchType == 'rental') {
   $('#form').attr('action','http://www.floridaspropertymanagement.com/search-results.php');
}
$('#form').submit();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick'n'dirty

```
$str = 'www.xyz.com/search-results.php?city%5B%5D=Boynton+Beach&proptype=rental&foreclosure=&price_from=0&price_to=0&footage_from=&footage_to=&bedrooms_from=&bedrooms_to=&bathrooms_from=&bathrooms_to=&pets=&year_from=&year_to=&pool=';

preg_match('/proptype=([^&]*)/i', $str, $matches);
$host = "";
if (isset($matches[1])) {
    switch ($matches[1]) {
        case 'rental':
        $host = 'www.xyzRentals.com';
    break;
    }
}

$str=preg_replace('#([^\/]*)\/#i', $host . '/', $str);


header("Location: $str");
```

Answer (score 0):

`header("Location: [...]);` sends out a 301 --

so if your $_POST variable is always going to be `proptype` = then,

`header("Location: {$yourURLwithLotsOfGETparams}&proptype={$_POST['proptype']});`